# Create an object inside a vector that is contained by another

Tags: c++, vector, std

I want to create an object inside a std::vector avoiding creating it out and then push_back() him.
I heard about emplace_back() but i couldn't use it in this situation:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> info;
```

Then, anyone know how to create the string info inside the second vector and this vector in the last position of the first? Anything similar to this but without using *info2* and the push_back():

```
std::vector<std::string> info2;
info2.emplace_back("a");
info.push_back(info2);
```

Comment: I would recommend you avoid these "two-dimensional vectors" and then your problem goes away. Either keep a `std::map<std::vector<std::string>>` (if your inner dimension is not fixed) or keep a `std::vector<std::string>` and lay out a co-ordinate translation around it (if your inner dimension is fixed). Then you don't have unnecessary object creation, which is exactly the problem you're coming up against here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `emplace_back` a whole vector, like this

```
info.emplace_back(std::vector<string>{"a"});
```

However dealing with vector of vectors is cumbersome so you may rethink your design, as suggested by Lightness Races in Orbit.